# What is the right name for an "inversive" function

Tags: functions, terminology

Say, $y = x^2$ is the function, while $x = \sqrt{y}$ is its "inversion". I'm not sure what is the right name for this. What is it?

Comment: [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function), though you have to be careful about the domain so it's a function

Comment: @J.W.Tanner maybe you can turn your comment into an answer and I'll happily accept it?

Comment: The inverse , and when a confusion is possible (with the *multiplicative* inverse, $\frac1x$), the *functional* inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function that "reverses" another function is called its [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function).

Note that $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb R$ does not have an inverse function,

because, for example, both $2$ and $-2$ get mapped to $4$ by $f$.

But $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb R^{\ge0}$ does have an inverse function.